# Azure event triggered function for blob creation

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I've been trying to create an azure function which will move blobs from one container to another. For this purpose, I created a function following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-debug-event-grid-trigger-local).

Now when I add blob in container, I can debug the rest in local. Problem starts when I try to deploy the function. I'm using CICD for function deployment. After that, when I'm trying to configure the event subscription, it's failing.

1. I cannot edit the ENDPOINT DETAILS when creating event subscription
2. If I try to "Add event grid subscription", it gives a strange error message - Deployment has failed with the following error:

> {"code":"Url validation","message":"The attempt to validate the
>   provided endpoint
>   https://.azurewebsites.net/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig
>   failed. For more details, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation."}

All the tutorials I found are either irrelevant or outdated. Does anyone have any suggestion what I should do or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in adance

Comment: What's your function runtime, v1 or v2?

Comment: My runtime is V1.

Comment: how are you creating the subscription ? arm template ? powerhsell? could you give more details, some code ?

Comment: I was creating the subscription manually from portal. And I think I found the problem. I deleted the blob container used in filter after I created the subscription (to delete the existing blobs in one go). Looks like the reference to container got lost after that. I assumed the subscription will be loosely coupled. :)